# Why testing with -f in bash returns true when no arguments are provided to the test?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I have the following piece of code in a script file:

```
if [ -f $FILEPATH ] ; then
    cp $FILEPATH ~/some/other/dir
fi
```

Now, due to an error in this same script file some lines above this piece of code the variable $FILEPATH doesn't receive a value and is undefined, so what really is executed is:

```
if [ -f ] ; then
    cp $FILEPATH ~/some/other/dir
fi
```

In this situation I would expect this test to either throw an error (because there's no argument to -f) or to return false (because it looks for a file with no name), but the test returns true and the contents of the if condition are executed.

I'm wondering how bash interprets this test to return true in this scenario. What's the real test done?

I'm running bash version 4.3.48 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the [POSIX behavior](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) for the `test` command:

The command `test`, with

> 1 argument:
>
> Exit true (0) if $1 is not null; otherwise, exit false.

Hence `test -f` (or, equivalently, `[ -f ]`) is called with one non-null argument, so it returns `true`.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the duplicate, didn't find that question when looking this up.